# Can't decode objectID into an array

Tags: json, mongodb, go

I have this code in Golang

```
    var usu models.Usuario
    condicion := bson.M{
        "email":email,
    }
    err := col.FindOne(context.TODO(), condicion).Decode(&usu)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Login instatisfactorio por error "+err.Error())
        return usu, err
    }
```

And I have this error

> 2020-02-04 16:13:10 default[20200203t231424]  2020/02/04 16:13:10
>   Login instatisfactorio por error cannot decode objectID into an array

The error is the

```
type Usuario struct {
    ID         bson.RawValue `bson:'_id' json:'id, omitempty'`
```

How can I DECODE results that include a "bson.RawValue"? I need the User ID

Thanks

UPGRADE :
Hi, I have now `.Hex()` working, but I have '00000000000000' as a result. Look.

```
    var resultado models.Usuario

    err := col.FindOne(context.TODO(), condicion).Decode(&resultado)

    log.Println("Nombre : "+resultado.Nombre)
    log.Println("Apellido : "+resultado.Apellidos)
    log.Println("ID : "+resultado.ID.Hex())
```

And this is the Model

```
type Usuario struct {
    ID         primitive.ObjectID `bson:'_id' json:'_id, omitempty'`
    Nombre     string `bson:"nombre" json:"nombre,omitempty"`
    Apellidos  string `bson:"apellidos" json:"apellidos,omitempty"`
    Password   string `bson:"password" json:"password,omitempty"`
    Email      string `bson:"email" json:"email"`
}
```

I have this in the Database

[image: MongoDB Collection]

Answer (score 1):

ObjectID is of type `primitive.ObjectID`. If you change the type of ID to  `primitive.ObjectID`, it should be able to decode it.

Comment: Hi Burak, I had thousands of code lines in my App.. If I change this I need to refurbish a lot of lines..

Comment: You could try using a separate struct for DB operations containing an ObjectID, and translate that to this struct you're using.

Comment: Have you an Example ? I don't understand your point... I have now changed my structs with the Primitive format... I have a Login that create a Payload with the user struct... And I need to include in this struct... the User ID, for use this ID in every API route to make a lot of operations in a lot of Collections

Comment: I need to retrieve and convert in String, the ObjectID after a single FindONE(), not after InsertONE()

Comment: If you changed your struct to use primitive.ObjectID, then you can get the string version of it using ID.Hex().

Comment: Hi, I have now the .Hex() working, but I have '00000000000000' as result.

Comment: Is that when you read it from the db? It is uninitialized. Are you sure you read a record?

Comment: Yes... I have results when I do an log.Println() `
2020-02-07 00:40:02 default[20200206t213613]  2020/02/07 00:40:02 Nombre : German
2020-02-07 00:40:02 default[20200206t213613]  2020/02/07 00:40:02 Apellido : Serrizuela
2020-02-07 00:40:02 default[20200206t213613]  2020/02/07 00:40:02 ID : 000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Tell me if the ID struct is right, I names ID  and 'json : _id'  this '_id' is valid ? I'm trying to allow there the original ObjectId

Comment: Names look right. However, your data may have an _id that is not an ObjectId. You can see that by querying it using mongo command line. See if _id shows as ObjectId, or as string.

Comment: Yes, I have this `_id
:5e358cc1bdcae21098710f9c
email:"aaa@gmail.com"
password:"$2a$08$Xhgw7r0yqnzMo8ysQhHdGuCMQi71m13LmcM.LJQKRH1DuK2dUTTTm"
nombre:""
apellidos:""
edad:0

Comment: That looks like a string. An objectid would look like _id: ObjectId(5e...)

Comment: What sintaxis you recommend ? I'm desperate, I'm hold in this problem from several days. Thanks

Comment: This is not a question of syntax, it is a question of what data you have in the db. If mongo command line shows _id:"5e...", then you have string ids in the database. If it shows _id:ObjectId("5e...") then you have object ids. Define your structs to match that.  Change that ID in the struct to a string, see if you can read your data.

Comment: Look the Added image.. I have an ObjectId field

Comment: Your tags are wrong. Change it to: `bson:"_id" json:"_id, omitempty"`. Note the double-quotes.

Comment: WOW... It's amazing.. a single quotes and all be terrific... you're very kind.. THANKS THANKS